# Getting an error trying to map through a list in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to print out all the factors of every number in a list.

Here is my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) 
{

val list_of_numbers = List(1,4,6)

def get_factors(list_of_numbers:List[Int]) : Int =
{
return list_of_numbers.foreach{(1 to _).filter {divisor => _ % divisor == 0}}
}

println(get_factors(list_of_numbers));

}
```

I want the end result to contain a single list that will hold all the numbers which are factors of any of the numbers in the list. So the final result should be (1,2,3,4,6). Right now, I get the following error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => 1.to(x$1))
return list_of_numbers.foreach{(1 to _).filter {divisor => _ % divisor == 0}}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Given your description, the signature for your method should be `def get_factors(list_of_numbers:List[Int]) : List[Int]`

Comment: As side note, you don't need to declare `return` and it's use is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are wrong here.

First, `foreach` takes a function `A => Unit` as an argument, meaning that it's really just for causing side effects.

Second your use of `_`, you can use _ when the function uses each argument once.

Lastly your expected output seems to be getting rid of duplicates (1 is a factor for all 3 inputs, but it only appears once).

```
list_of_numbers flatMap { i => (1 to i) filter {i % _ == 0 }} distinct
```

will do what you are looking for.

flatMap takes a function from `A => List[B]` and produces a simple `List[B]` as output, `list.distinct` gets rid of the duplicates.

Comment: this seems promising. But a few questions. It prints List(1, 2, 4, 3, 6). Why does it also print the "List". also, is there a way to make this totally immutable? The element i changes for every value in the list, is there a way to make this more functional

Comment: The printing of `List` is because the toString function on List prints it that way. Getting a simple comma separated string from the list can be done using `list.mkString(",")`.

As far as mutation, there is none, i is an argument passed into the anonymous function, which is run for each item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `_` shorthand once in a function (except for some special cases), and even then not always.
Try spelling it out instead:

```
list_of_numbers.foreach { n =>
   (1 to n).filter { divisor => n % divisor == 0 }
}
```

This will compile.

There are other problems with your code though. 
`foreach` returns a `Unit`, but you are requiring an `Int` for example. 
Perhaps, you wanted a `.map` rather than `.foreach`, but that would still be a `List`, not an `Int`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this expression returns a Unit which is probably not what OP wants

Comment: yeah ... just realized/added that

Comment: `map` would return a `List[List[Int]` you need `flatMap` to unnest the result.

Comment: yeah ... `.flatMap` would still return a `List`, while the function result wants an `Int`. I am not sure what the intent is here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are several problems with your code.

First, *foreach* is a method which yields *Unit* (like *void* in Java). You want to yield something so you should use a *for comprehension*.

Second, in your divisor-test function, you've specified both the unnamed parameter ("_") and the named parameter (divisor).

The third problem is that you expect the result to be *Int* (in the code) but *List[Int]* in your description.

The following code will do what you want (although it will repeat factors, so you might want to pass it through *distinct* before using the result):

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val list_of_numbers = List(1, 4, 6)
  def get_factors(list_of_numbers: List[Int]) = for (n <- list_of_numbers; r = 1 to n; f <- r.filter(n%_ == 0)) yield f
  println(get_factors(list_of_numbers))
}
```

Note that you need two generators ("<-") in the *for comprehension* in order that you end up with simply a *List*. If you instead implemented the filter part in the yield expression, you would get a *List[List[Int]]*.

Comment: this seems to work but the result is (1,1,2,4,1, 2, 3, 6) and I need to remove duplicates to get (1,2,3,4,6)

Comment: @lalakers4life indeed. apply *distinct* to the result as noted. And thank you for the up vote. Much appreciated.

Comment: Another question, is there another approach to doing this so that we don't create an element like n or r that mutates within the code? I want to try to program this in a purely functional style where the data is immutable

Comment: Good question. However, there is nothing mutable here. *n* and *r* are variables only in the algebraic sense. Each value of *n* or *r* that is generated by the for comprehension is immutable, that's to say equivalent to a *val* (although you don't have to use the *val* keyword).

Comment: As you probably know, the form with *for comprehension* and *flatMap* are equivalent (the compiler "desugars" the for comprehension into map/flatMap calls). But using the for comprehension is very much idiomatic functional programming as it makes the meaning clearer (I think).